# Slider in react component returns 'cannot read property style of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Tried to create a component for a slider, but for some reason it doesn't work!

When rendering for the first time, I get the following error: 'cannot read property style of undefined...'.

When I tried to log **x[slideIndex-1]** I first get undefined and then I get proper values after the onClick event listener fired.

Also when I logged **x.length** before clicking any of the buttons I get 0, but after onClick it switches to 4.

Here is the whole component file :

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => {
  var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

  function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

  function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__img");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display="block";
}

  return (
    <div className="content-container">
      <img className="slider__img" src="../images/foo.jpg"/>
      <img className="slider__img" src="../images/foo2.jpg"/>
      <img className="slider__img" src="../images/foo3.jpg"/>
      <img className="slider__img" src="../images/foo4.jpg"/>
      <button onClick={()=>plusDivs(1)}>Next</button>
      <button onClick={()=>plusDivs(-1)}>Previous</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you are using react you should think about how you are modifying elements. Using document.getElementsByClassName is not the right way. How about using the state?

Answer (score 0):

Like pointed out in the comments. It is bad practice to directly manipulate DOM elements when you are using React. React uses a virtual DOM. In order to minimize DOM manipulations, React first figures out all the changes that have to be applied in the virtual DOM and then then it is actually rendered to the real DOM. That is why manipulating DOM elements yourself can be considered an anti-pattern when using React.

One way to solve your issue would be the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      slideIndex: 1,
      images: [
        '../images/foo.jpg',
        '../images/foo2.jpg',
        '../images/foo3.jpg',
        '../images/foo4.jpg'
      ]
    };
  }

  pludDivs(n) {
    const { images } = this.state;
    if (n > images.length) {
      this.setState({ slideIndex: 1 });
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      this.setState({ slideIndex: images.length - 1 });      
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { images, sliderIndex } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="content-container">
        <img className="slider__img" src={images[slideIndex]} />
        <button onClick={() => plusDivs(1)}>Next</button>
        <button onClick={() => plusDivs(-1)}>Previous</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This helped in terms of pointing the right direction, however code itself didn't work. There are typos in defining plusDivs(pludDivs) and passing state to render slideIndex (sliderIndex), but even with correcting them it didn't seem to work. Will try to get this working myself and get back if I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't look really clean and probably has potential for improvements, but it works! Thanks guys for pointing me in right direction regarding DOM and virtual DOM!

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Slider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      slideIndex: 0,
      images: [
        '../images/foo1.jpg',
        '../images/foo2.jpg',
        '../images/foo3.jpg',
        '../images/foo4.jpg'
      ]
    };
  }

  plusDivs(n) {
    const { images, slideIndex } = this.state;
    if(n<0){
      if(slideIndex>0){
        this.setState((prevState)=>({
          slideIndex : prevState.slideIndex - 1
        }));
      } else {
        this.setState(()=>({
          slideIndex:images.length-1
        }))
      }

    }
    if(n>0){
      if(slideIndex<images.length-1){
        this.setState((prevState)=>({
          slideIndex : prevState.slideIndex +1
        }))
      } else {
        this.setState(()=>({
          slideIndex : 0
        }))
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { images, slideIndex } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="content-container">
        <img className="slider__img" src={images[slideIndex]} />
        <button onClick={() => this.plusDivs(1)}>Next</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.plusDivs(-1)}>Previous</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first remove folder react-native-image-slider-box from node_modules folder
and then install
yarn add megamaxs1234/react-native-image-slider-box

Comment: You can better format and enhance this answer with docs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).